# Unable to find database location

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am new to postgreSQL and was looking to use postgres with a java app. I am not sure why but I can't find where the location of db files are stored in postgres and have searched everywhere imaginable. I used the query show data_directory; from there I did a search on the C drive and couldn't find it. Is there a certain way I need to reference it in java? Is there a default location where postgres typically stores the data? I tried "jdbc:postgresql://my ip address:5432/and my database name". I attempted to use the location given in the show data_directory query here was the stack trace output

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: invalid database address: jdbc::C:/postgreSQL/9.2/data/spetmodb.db
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:74)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:64)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at databaseManip.Dbmanipbase.addUserToDB(Dbmanipbase.java:81)
    at Kapowmainn.main(Kapowmainn.java:20)
```

I wish I could be more helpful but if you have any questions I will gladly answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you're new to Java and JDBC, too.  You don't access PostgreSQL or any other relational database by file; you do it using the java.sql package and JDBC.  You'll need the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) and the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).  Download it, put it in your CLASSPATH, and [connect this way](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html).

Make sure that the PostgreSQL listener is up and running and LISTENING on port 5432.  Type `netstat -a` in a command shell to see if that's true.

Make sure you can connect to the database using the PostgreSQL admin console.  If it can't connect, Java can't either.

I'd recommend posting your code (if it's small enough).  It'll make it easier to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to get it working correctly.

Comment: What made the difference?  What did you change?  Being less obtuse about the solution might help someone else someday.

Comment: The path I was using was incorrect. Using the ip address listed in the pg_hba.config file and the server port number I was able to connect to the database example: jdbc:postgresql://hba.config ip address :port #/databasename, "role username", "role password" . I was also using the wrong jdbc driver. I downloaded the postgresql jdbc driver but was using the sqlite jdbc driver.